# If statement isn't working with CSS value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My code here isn't working...any other idea as to what to to put in as the if statement's condition? Any help is appreciated greatly. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<img class="image image1" src="images/spongebob1.jpg" />
```

CSS:

```
.image {
height: 94%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
animation: moveSlider 5s 1;
-webkit-animation: moveSlider 5s 1;
}
@keyframes moveSlider {
from {left:0px;}
to {left:200px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes moveSlider {
from {opacity:0;}
to {opacity:1;}
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image2, .image3, .image4, .image5").hide();
    if ($(".image1").css('opacity') === '1') {
        $(".image1").hide();
    } 
});
```

Comment: unrelated, but for these, `image` should probably be the class and `image1` should be the ID.

Comment: What value did you get when you debugged your code (or used an alert box) "alert($(".image1").css('opacity'))" ?

Comment: Have you tried it without the strict equality (`===`)?

Comment: Just console.log the value of .css('opacity'). It almost definitely isn't 1.

Comment: What do you get when you try `alert($('.image1').css('opacity'));` ? That should give you an idea of what's going on. I suspect you might need to use `==`. Or maybe opacity is really `100`. Something like that.

Comment: I console.logged `$(".image1").css("opacity"); and got 1...

Comment: Oh... `if ($('.image1').is(':visible')) {` worked like a charm... Thanks @PJ McCormick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be you're using 1 as a string. === will not convert the string to an integer

```
if ($(".image1").css('opacity') === '1') {
    $(".image1").hide();
}
```

try === 1 instead of '1'

Comment: That was my first try... and that didn't work. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing line 3 of your JS to this:

```
if ($('.image1').is(':visible')) {
```

Also, try to be consistent with how you use your " vs ' --you're mixing them in the original line. This is mostly just to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image2, .image3, .image4, .image5").hide();
    if ($(".image1").css({'opacity':'1'}) === true) {
        $(".image1").hide();
    } 
});
```